# Android OpenGL ES doesn't display my triangulated shape using TRIANGLES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to display shapes as different as one likes using OpenGL ES on an Android device. Problem is that my code doesn't even work for easy shapes like a rectangle (which I am going to use below).

I think somthing is wrong with the `glTranslatef`. I've adjusted all the values but I can't figure out what it is.

The Rectangle is defined by the points `P(0,0,0), P(0,1,0), P(1,1,0), P(1,0,0)`. In the `Activity` I implemented the `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` like this:

```
private static FloatBuffer getVertexCoords() {
    float coords[] = {
        0f, 0f, 0f, // first triangle first point
        0f, 1f, 0f, // first triangle second point
        1f, 1f, 0f, // first triangle third point
        1f, 1f, 0f, // second triangle first point
        1f, 0f, 0f, // second triangle second point
        0f, 0f, 0f, // second triangle third point                
        }
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(coords.length * 4); // n coords * 4 bytes per float
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer trianglesVB = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    trianglesVB.put(coords);
    trianglesVB.position(0);
    return trianglesVB;
}


@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
   gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
   gl.glLoadIdentity();
   gl.glTranslatef(0f, 0f, -4f);
   gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); // glBegin
   gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
   gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, getVertexCoords());
   gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 2 * 3 * 3); // triangles * points * coords
   gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); // glEnd
   int error = gl.glGetError();
   if (error != GL10.GL_NO_ERROR) {
       Log.e(TAG, "OpenGL ES Error: " + error);
   }
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    // think this one doesn't matter
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    // white background
    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);         // front face is clockwise

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a projection matrix in there somewhere. If you don't set one, then you are drawing directly in normalized device coordinates, of which the only valid z-values are from (-1 to 1).

Simply your triangle is outside of the depth range displayed.

Try adding a simple projection matrix to onSurfaceCreated:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-10, 10, -10, 10, 0, 10);
```

Comment: I added glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION) and glOrthox(...) which makes the upper part of the screen flash up in red (the triangle's color but still confusing because I changed the coordinates and it remains at the same position). And after a moment of vitality it disappears in a fraction of a second. So?